# Windows 7 Wireless unable to detect network after windows update

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, wifi-driver

Ever since a windows update my laptop, an asus ul30vt, has been unable to detect wireless networks. I found that I could get it to detect them if I uninstall the drivers and reinstall. I reinstalled the operating system fresh and the issue still happens. I also bought a USB wifi dongle and I still continue to have the issue. I am stuck on how to fix this issue. Fresh install of windows 7 and new wifi stick and the issue continues. I'm not sure how to go about fixing this. Here are the few things I know about this so far...

1. Started after a windows update.
2. Affects any Wireless network device
3. disable/reenable doesn't fix this
4. toggling the Laptop's Disable Wireless key doesn't bring the
   wireless back
5. Reinstall from the locked Recovery partition doesn't fix the issue
6. update of wireless driver didn't fix it
7. Tried a Winsock repair on it in the old OS Install with no luck

Given that it does work when uninstall and reinstall and the new wifi works but suffers from the same issue, makes me think this is a solvable software related issue.

Laptop: ASUS UL30VT Operating System: Windows 7 Professional Internal Wireless card: Atheros ar9285 USB Wireless stick: TP-LINK TL-WN725N v2.0

Comment: If this happens after you reinstall Windows then its not a software problem.  The problem is likely the access point your trying to connect to.

Comment: I have tried this in multiple networks, home, work, public

Comment: If it was a software problem, when you installed Windows again, the problem would have been solved.  Have you tried not installing the windows update in question that causes the problem?

Comment: I have not. when I reinstalled the machine the windows update had it's way with it.

Comment: That is something you will need to try.  You can manually uninstall the problem update if you want to try that..

Comment: How do I identify the problem update and manually uninstall it?

Comment: If you didn't go all "end of the world" on the original installation I could have walk you through it.

Comment: So at this point it's not possible to uninstall the updates?

Comment: No;  You will just have to uninstall each update one by one until you find the problem update.

Comment: How do I uninstall them one at a time?

Comment: Add/remove programs